# ORACLE IF-ELSE Branching complication

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a question regarding if else branching in oracle procedure. so i have this query,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE WELTESADMIN.SP_MST_ERC_UPD
(
    p_HEAD_MARK IN VARCHAR2,
    p_PROJECT_NAME IN VARCHAR2,
    p_COMP_TYPE IN VARCHAR2,
    p_ONSITE_UPD_QTY IN INTEGER,
    p_PREP_UPD_QTY IN INTEGER,
    p_ERECT_UPD_QTY IN INTEGER,
    p_QC_UPD_QTY IN INTEGER,
    p_UPD_SIGN IN VARCHAR
)
AS
/* IF NOT THEN.. ; WHEN THE RECORD EXISTS DO THIS... */
BEGIN 
UPDATE MST_ERC_UPD 
    SET 
        ONSITE_UPD_QTY = p_ONSITE_UPD_QTY,
        PREP_UPD_QTY = p_PREP_UPD_QTY,
        ERECT_UPD_QTY = p_ERECT_UPD_QTY,
        QC_UPD_QTY = p_QC_UPD_QTY
    WHERE
        HEAD_MARK = p_HEAD_MARK AND
        PROJECT_NAME = p_PROJECT_NAME AND
        COMP_TYPE = p_COMP_TYPE;

INSERT INTO DTL_ERC_UPD ( /* THIS ACTS AS A HISTORY TABLE THAT RECORDS EVERY OCCURENCE */
    HEAD_MARK, PROJECT_NAME, COMP_TYPE,
    ONSITE_UPD_QTY, PREP_UPD_QTY, ERECT_UPD_QTY, QC_UPD_QTY,
    UPD_DATE, UPD_SIGN, UPD_INFO
) VALUES (
    p_HEAD_MARK, p_PROJECT_NAME, p_COMP_TYPE,
    p_ONSITE_UPD_QTY, p_PREP_UPD_QTY, p_ERECT_UPD_QTY, p_QC_UPD_QTY,
    SYSDATE, p_UPD_SIGN, 'UPDATE'
);

/* WHEN THE RECORD IS NOT EXISTS DO THIS */      
            IF SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0 THEN
            INSERT INTO MST_ERC_UPD
                (
                    HEAD_MARK, PROJECT_NAME, COMP_TYPE,
                    ONSITE_UPD_QTY, PREP_UPD_QTY, ERECT_UPD_QTY, QC_UPD_QTY
                )
                VALUES
                (
                    p_HEAD_MARK, p_PROJECT_NAME, p_COMP_TYPE,
                    p_ONSITE_UPD_QTY, p_PREP_UPD_QTY, p_ERECT_UPD_QTY, p_QC_UPD_QTY
                );

            /* THIS ACTS AS A HISTORY TABLE THAT RECORDS EVERY OCCURENCE */
            INSERT INTO DTL_ERC_UPD
                (
                    HEAD_MARK, PROJECT_NAME, COMP_TYPE,
                    ONSITE_UPD_QTY, PREP_UPD_QTY, ERECT_UPD_QTY, QC_UPD_QTY,
                    UPD_DATE, UPD_SIGN, UPD_INFO
                )
                VALUES
                (         
                    p_HEAD_MARK, p_PROJECT_NAME, p_COMP_TYPE,
                    p_ONSITE_UPD_QTY, p_PREP_UPD_QTY, p_ERECT_UPD_QTY, p_QC_UPD_QTY,
                    SYSDATE, p_UPD_SIGN, 'NEWENTRY'
                );
            END IF;
COMMIT;
END SP_MST_ERC_UPD;
```

So the problem with my branching here is, The piece of query when the record is not exists is not executed (The new insertion with the 'NEWENTRY' status never get executed). Please help me with this branching problem... thanks

Comment: Use a debug to see what is happening with the SQL% something like `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQL%ROWCOUNT);` before that if. Do'nt forget to turn on the output

Comment: So i already debug every behavior the only problem is the insert after update (2nd block)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are testing if no rows where affected after `LAST` sql command

```
--UPDATE
--INSERT 
IF SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0 THEN
```

Which will never be true since your last command is an `INSERT` command. To test if your Update command changed something you have to create a variable to store the modified rows by the update command something like this:

```
...
AS
numChangedRows NUMBER;
BEGIN
   numChangedRows:=0; 
   --Your Update command
   numChangedRows:=SQL%ROWCOUNT;
   --Your insert command
   IF numChangedRows = 0 THEN
...
```

Comment: Thanks campos.. i figured it out that using trigger after update is more applicable in using this.

Comment: @KonzMama - you might want to look at the `merge` statement too; you might not need to use PL/SQL at all.